# Separate an even integer into a sum of 2,4,6 using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have to write a recursive method in Java that separates an even integer into a sum of 2,4,6 using recursion meanwhile there can not be 2 of same numbers in a row.

For example `n=8` returns:

```
([2,4,2], [2,6], [6,2])

(where [2,2,2,2], [2,2,4], [4,2,2], [4,4] are not allowed as answers)
```

I am looking for the algorithm to do this. At the moment I am thinking I need to give the method two parameters, one would be `int n` and other `ArrayList<Integer>` to store the found ways of separating. But I am having trouble thinking of an algorithm that could do this.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> subtractions(int n, ArrayList<Integer> integers){
    int sum = 0;
    for(Integer i:integers){
        sum += i;
    }
    if(n>2 && sum<n) {
        integers.add(n - 2);
        return subtractions(n - 2, integers);
    }
    integers.add(2);
    return integers;
}
```

This is what i have right now but it only gives me one answer in case of `n=8` and that is `[6,2]`

Could someone give me a starting place or something?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a whole level of complexity.  You shouldn't be dealing with Lists of Integers, you should be dealing with Lists of Lists of Integers.  This problem is more about data structures than it is about math.  My example solution:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> subtractions_recursive(int target, int exclude) {

    List<List<Integer>> solutions = new ArrayList<>();

    if (target == 0) { // base case for recursion
        List<Integer> empty = new ArrayList<>(); // ()
        solutions.add(empty); // (())
    } else {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 6 && target - i > -1; i += 2) {
            if (i == exclude) {
                continue;
            }

            List<List<Integer>> sub_solutions = subtractions_recursive(target - i, i); // ((4, 2), (6))

            for (List<Integer> sub_solution:sub_solutions) {
                sub_solution.add(0, i); // ((2, 4, 2), (2, 6))
            }

            solutions.addAll(sub_solutions);
        }
    }

    return solutions; // ((2, 4, 2), (2, 6), (6, 2))
}

public static List<List<Integer>> subtractions(int target) {
    return subtractions_recursive(target, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be related to the [Subset Sum Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). There´s also another article [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubsetSumProblem.html). Both articles are good to undesrtand the complexity of what you gonna face and develop your solution. You probably gonna need to adapt a little bit, to remove all subsets with sequences of same numbers in a row. 
Good Luck